# Is there a single term for "refer back"

Tags: single-word-requests

Take for example

"Hello there"

How do I refer back to "Hello there" without specifying "Hello there"

I guess it has to be somewhere along the line of being reflexive or meta

Is there such a term available?

Comment: Hi, if you can, please edit your post to make it clearer what you're asking for. As it is, I've no idea what the word you're looking for would mean. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what words you have considered and rejected, and, as well, as this is a _single word request_, you'll need to include a fill-in-the-blank example sentence for the word you're looking for. All this will help you get better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with *single-word-request*, and because of your question's title, it seems that what you're looking for is a single word that means *refer back*.

Such a word is [**reference**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference):

> **1 b** : to cite in or as a reference

In other words, your sentence would read:

> How do I *reference* "Hello there" without specifying "Hello there"?

---

If you actually mean to *literally* ask how to reference a previous sentence without writing it again, that's what pronouns are for:

> What I meant by **that** (sentence) was . . .